# OpenVPN Debian 9 Configuration: No Server-Client Connection with Ethernet

Tags: openvpn

I am currently trying to setup an OpenVPN server on my Debian 9 computer and am running into connection issues with the client. Currently, the server is physically connected to the client (running Windows) by ethernet through a switch, but the client is unable to establish a connection with the server (the server shows up as tun0 in ifconfig). I believe this to be a configuration issue somewhere but am unable to figure out where.

I am also behind a NAT network if that makes a difference. I have also temporarily disabled firewall on both computers for debugging purposes.

Are there any solutions as to why I cannot establish a connection? Thanks in advance.

I am following instructions on this page (I also use the shell script provided):
 [OpenVPN_Debian_9](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-debian-9-in-5-minutes/)

This is server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun  
sndbuf 0  
rcvbuf 0  
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt  
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt  
key /etc/openvpn/server.key  
dh /etc/openvpn/dh.pem  
auth SHA512  
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/ta.key 0
topology subnet  
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0  
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt  
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"  
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"  
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"  
keepalive 10 120  
cipher AES-256-CBC  
comp-lzo  
user nobody  
group nogroup  
persist-key  
persist-tun  
status openvpn-status.log  
verb 3  
crl-verify crl.pem
```

This is client.conf:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
```

client log

```
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.3 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)][LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Jul 14 2017
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017, LZO 2.10
Enter Management Password:
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]10.8.0.1:1194
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 UDP link local: (not bound)
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]10.8.0.1:1194
Tue Aug 01 09:33:40 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1501594420,WAIT,
Tue Aug 01 09:34:40 2017 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Tue Aug 01 09:34:40 2017 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Tue Aug 01 09:34:40 2017 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Tue Aug 01 09:34:40 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1501594480,RECONNECTING,tls-error
Tue Aug 01 09:34:40 2017 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Tue Aug 01 09:34:45 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]10.8.0.1:1194
```

Answer (score 0):

`UDP link remote: [AF_INET]10.8.0.1:1194` -- I don't know how you have your network setup but you **cannot** connect to the server on the tun interface at 10.8.0.1 .. `--remote 10.8.0.1` is wrong you must use the main IP or public IP and forward the port at your router/firewall.